# jQuery - Show field based on value of a type-hidden on refresh

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create something in jQuery and having a bit of problems with it. I'm not too adept on the framework, so I'm sure this is all wrong.

Anyways, the ultimate goal is a full form that contains 3 radio buttons - depending on the value of the button, a LI is shown. I have all of that done, but my problem is coming with validation. If something fails then the page is reloaded and the div that was selected doesn't show without clicking another radio first, then back to the original. This process is basically the same as someone came up with here.

Here's what I got so far.

**HTML**

```
 <li> <label> License (radio) </label>
 <label for="commercial" class="checkBox"> Commercial </label> 
     <input type="radio" name="license" value="commercial" id="commercial" class="checkBox" <?php echo set_radio('license', 'commercial'); ?> />
    <label for="abandonware" class="checkBox"> Abandonware </label>
        <input type="radio" name="license" value="abandonware" id="abandonware" class="checkBox" <?php echo set_radio('license', 'abandonware'); ?> />
    <label for="freeware" class="checkBox"> Freeware </label>
        <input type="radio" name="license" value="freeware" id="freeware" class="checkBox" <?php echo set_radio('license', 'freeware'); ?> />
   </li>
```

This is followed by three LI's that contain id="commercial, abandonware, and freeware" and class="licenseli"

My jQuery is, as said, something from here.

```
 $('li.licenseli').hide();
    $('input[name=license]:radio').change(function(){
    var Type = $(this).val(); // Get value of radio
    $('li.licenseli').slideUp(); // Hide non-selected
    $('li#'+Type).slideDown(); // Show Selected
});
```

So what I need help with is I have a hidden input that retrieves the value of the radio box from validation - I want to take this value (or the radio's if possible?) and have the original selected option's LI already visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try triggering the change event on the radios once when the page has fully loaded, to correctly set the visual state of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.licenseli').hide();
    $('input[name=license]:radio').change(function(){
        var Type = $(this).val(); // Get value of radio
        $('li.licenseli').slideUp(); // Hide non-selected
        $('li#'+Type).slideDown(); // Show Selected
    }).change();
});
```

Also see [`.triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/), which behaves similarly.

Comment: This has gotten me further than anything else I've tried in the past 2 days, but now on refresh it's only bringing up the "freeware" li. I checked out .triggerHandler, and it's latin to me.

Comment: I just used console.log() on Type and it seems it's returning all three values at the same time. Unless I'm not using Firebug right. --Took me longer than 5 minutes to get that up, sorry for the double post.

Comment: After a little bit of personal error, I've gotten it to work perfectly. I change the var line to - [ var Type = $('input:radio[name=license]:checked').val(); ] and then switched from slideUp/Down to just simple Show/Hide and now everything works just fine. Thanks!